# Shapes disappear when I change camera settings

Tags: java, 3d, processing

flow-ers! I'm learning a fascinating language: **Processing**. I started to use **P3D** and tried to make **'First-person' camera** in 3D world. The matter is, when I move my mouse(means I changed my camera option), 3D shapes such as spheres and cubes seem to be cut by a transparent plane.

I made some attempts to deal with my problem, (e.g. changing 3rd factor of camera()) but it still doesn't work. Let me show my codes.

This is the main drawing part of my program.

```
pushMatrix();
translate(width/2, height, 0);

// P is player-class, and view method controls the camera option
P.view(P.looking_at());

fill(0); stroke(255);
for (int i=0; i<1000; i+=1) {
  if (isNear(shapes[i])) // just checking for distance, it doesn't matter
    shapes[i].locate();
}

popMatrix(); // now, the origin is top left
```

and this is locating function of the shapes.

```
void locate() {
  // these are coordinate of the shape
  translate(location.x, location.y, location.z); 
  // sphere or cube
  translate(-location.x, -location.y, -location.z);
}
```

finally, this is what I wrote for P.view():

```
void view(PVector watch_point) { // camera setting
  hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
  camera(location.x, location.y, location.z, // these are coordinate of player
    watch_point.x, watch_point.y, watch_point.z, // sight direction, updated when the mouse is moved
    0, -1, 0); // 3rd factor for camera
  lights();
}
```

I expect the "normal view" as in real world, but when I look at some shapes squarely, they disappear! **They only seem normally when I leer at them, and the sculpture steadily fades away when I move my sight to them**; more specifically, it it looks like it was cut by a plane. Please help me solving this problem. (Or is there any mis-coding in my codes?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 3D shapes such as spheres and cubes seem to be cut by a transparent plane.

Probably the model is clipped by the near or far plane of the projection.
You've to increase the distance to the far plane or decrease the distance to the near plane, when you set the perspective projection.
If the objects are clipped (cut) by the far plane, then increase the 4th parameter (`zFar`), when you set the perspective projection ([`perspective()`](https://processing.org/reference/perspective_.html)).
If the objects are clipped by the near plane, then decrease the distance to the near plane (`zNear`).
But note the condition `0 < zNear` and  `zNear < zFar` has to be fulfilled in any case.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.